# How to use Google Calendar API with my Android App?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to use Google Calender from my Android Application.

I read through the Documentation but I it asks me to use "Signing certificate fingerprint SHA1" for my application.

How can I generate SHA1 for my application release and debug versions from Eclipse ADT.

Does Eclipse ADT auto generate it for me? Does it generate a new one each time I tried to test the application in the emulator?

NOTE: I found a relative question at SO but the answers are not answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for generating the SHA1 fingerprint is the same for all Google services, so you can follow the step by step instructions [for enabling API access in the Google API console](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#step_1_enable_the_google_api), but make sure you enable the Google Calendar API. You'll want to register your `debug.keystore` file for debug builds and your signing `keystore` file for release.

Note, if you are targeting Ice Cream Sandwich (v14)+ devices, you can also use the [built in Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), which provides access to a device's calendars including Google Calendars for the current user.

Comment: Ok, in the link provided it say <path-to-debug-or-production-keystore> where is that path? if my project is at "/home/username/Workspace/teamBproject" I am using Eclipse with ADT in Ubuntu

Comment: @MIH1406 - in Eclipse, go to the Window Menu->Preferences->Android->Build. You should see a path to 'Default debug keystore' - that's where your debug keystore is. For a production keystore, those are initially created when you use the Android->Export Signed Application option (when right clicking on a project in Eclipse)